# Commons DBUtils Oracle 11.2.0.4 with Java 1.7 Binding parameters SQLException ORA-00942

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, java-7, apache-commons-dbutils

I'm working with Oracle Database 11.2.0.4 with ojdbc6.jar, and I'm using apache commons dbutils v1.7, with JDK 7. So I'm using the QueryRunner and its method in this function

```
private <T> List<T> executeQueryAndReturnBeanList(String query, Class<T> className, Object... param) throws SQLException {

     Connection connection = getDBConnectionInstance();

     DbUtils.loadDriver("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

     ResultSetHandler<List<T>> beanListHandler = new BeanListHandler<>(className,new BasicRowProcessor(new GenerousBeanProcessor()));

     QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner();

     List<T> list = runner.query(connection, query, beanListHandler, param);

     return list;
}
```

and everything works fine with select query without binding parameters

`SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE GRUPPO = 1 AND LANG = 'en_US'`

But when I excute this query

`String query = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE  WHERE GRUPPO = ? AND LANG = ?";`

It gives me this SQL Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 Query: SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE GRUPPO = ? AND LANG = ? Parameters: [1, en_US]
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:527)
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:391)
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:252)
        at mypackage.executeQueryAndReturnBeanList(JDBCFunctions.java:199)
```

I really don't know why. I tried to use **:P1, :P2** or **:1, :2** instead of **?** to bind parameters but nothing it happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, take a look to this post. I think it is a similar issue with parameters incorrectly parsed when using Apache DBUtils: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666622/apache-dbutils-changing-column-name-in-update-sql/35033943?noredirect=1#comment60591166_35033943

Answer (score 0):

Group is a reserved word and cannot be used as a column or table name. Most probably you have a quoted column name such as `"GROUP"` within the table.

So, need to query as
`SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE "GROUP" = 1 AND LANG = 'en_US'`

Quoted table names should be case sensitive, unlike unquoted ones.

The above one is the basic mistake, while the error(`ORA-00942`) suggests that your application connects to different schema than the schema in which successfully tested the query.

Comment: Sorry I change the name of the column name here for privacy. The real name is not GROUP. I update my request

Comment: What do you get by this `select user from dual` from the application ? Is that contained as the username in your connection string? @Orifedex

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I inserted " on every column and table's name and now it works. For example:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM \"PEOPLE\"  WHERE \"GRUPPO\" = ? AND \"LANG\" = ?"
```