# apache commons dbutils malformed sql

Tags: apache-commons, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using QueryRunner to fetch some records from the DB
seems like commons dbutils will produce malformed sql :ACCOUNT_NUMBERIKE

```
   accountList = run.query("SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_KEY, ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM V_ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER like ? order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER asc", getResultSetHandlerForLikeAccount(),
                              accountNumber + "%");
```

anyone else  encounter this issue before?

```
    ERROR com.xerox.implteam.devrox.client.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "ACCOUNT_NUMBERIKE": invalid identifier
     Query: SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_KEY, ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM V_ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER like ? order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER asc Parameters: [34%]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:350)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:288)
    at com.xerox.implteam.devrox.client.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl.getAccountSearchBeanByLikeAccountNumber(AccountDAOImpl.java:55)
    at com.xerox.implteam.devrox.client.bo.AccountBO.getAccountSearchBeanByLikeAccountNumber(AccountBO.java:41)
    at com.xerox.implteam.devrox.client.controllers.AutoCompleteController.preparePageModel(AutoCompleteController.java:43)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.addon.impl.runtime.addonServlet.handleGetPage(addonServlet.java:207)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.addon.impl.runtime.addonServlet.handlePage(addonServlet.java:173)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.addon.impl.runtime.addonServlet.service(addonServlet.java:96)
    at javax.servlet.http.Httimplteamervlet.service(Httimplteamervlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.tabs.TabsFilter.doFilter(TabsFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.virtualFS.VirtualFileSystemFilter.doFilter(VirtualFileSystemFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.security.csrf.web.CsrfGuardFilterProxy.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilterProxy.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.authentication.ProdSecurityEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ProdSecurityEnforcementFilter.java:157)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttimplteamessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttimplteamessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.http.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.security.BrowserSecurityFilter.doFilter(BrowserSecurityFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.http.RequestResponseFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.encoding.MultilingualSupportFilter.doFilter(MultilingualSupportFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.config.StartupErrorFilter.doFilter(StartupErrorFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Seems like the culprit is ojdbc6.jar - version 12.1.0.1.x downgrading to 11.2.0.4 its working with now issues I am wondering if anyone else encounter the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629438/sqlsyntaxerrorexception-when-using-like-with-ojdbc7-jar/25431409#25431409

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBUTILS-125