# Oracle ojdbc7 driver 12.1.0.2 issue

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ojdbc

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID_TABLE_1
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE TABLE_1.STRING_FIELD=(
   SELECT ANOTHER_STRING FROM ANOTHER_TABLE      
   WHERE ID_ANOTHER_TABLE = 1) 
AND TABLE_1.FIELD_2= :PARAM
```

When I prepare the statement, everything is fine. But when I call getParameterMetaData(), an exception occurs:

*Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*

```
private static Pair<JDBCResources, Integer> execSQL(Connection conn,   String sqlStatement, String params, boolean executeUpdate) {
  try {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement); //OK
    ParameterMetaData paramData = ps.getParameterMetaData(); //java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
```

The **exception** comes if I use Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 JDBC Driver -> **ojdbc7.jar** (3,698,857 bytes)
**It worked with** the Java 6 JDBC driver -> **ojdbc6.jar** (1,988,051 bytes)

What's wrong in this SQL statement? Since I'm using Java 8, can I use the ojdbc7 driver even on Oracle Database X / XI?

Comment: You can use the ojdbc7 driver even if you're using Java 8.  The 7 in ojdbc7 just means it was compiled and build using Java 7.  Same with ojdbc6.jar, it was compiled and built with Java 6.  Have you tried using an ojdbc8 jar?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629438/sqlsyntaxerrorexception-when-using-like-with-ojdbc7-jar) might be related.

Comment: Parameters need to be denoted by `?` in plain JDBC, not as `:param`

Comment: @Brandon G Using ojdbc8 worked! thank you!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You're right, but replacing the param name with a '?' doesn't change the issue. I'm using a NamedParameterStatement class that replaces param names with '?'

Comment: The line `PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);` will **not** accept `:param` as a valid placeholder - if that is not the code you are using, then please add the real code you use.

Comment: The code I posted works perfecty with thousands of query with named params and prepareStatement accepts :param (tested with ojdbc6 and ojdbc8)